# How can I pass a parameter into a constructor of type of a class I have created?

Tags: java

For example:
I have created a Publisher class and I pass into a constructor.

```
public Book(String pulicationTitle, Date publicationDate,  Publisher publisher,  String ISBN_10, String ISBN_13, String authorName) {
    super(pulicationTitle, publicationDate, publisher);
    ISBN_10 = ISBN_10;
    ISBN_13 = ISBN_13;
    this.authorName = authorName;
    bookCounter++;
}
```

And then in my testing class in which I excute:

```
Book book2 = new Book(pulicationTitle, publicationDate, publisher, ISBN_10, ISBN_13,   authorName);
```

In my Publisher class there is a method called  getPublisherId() and in my testing class I have to pass that id.
This what I did in my testing class:

```
Date date = new Date();
Publisher pub = new Publisher("Cenage Learning", "13344-Tobean Drive,Independence, KY 45536", "Josef Blumenfield");
Book book = new Book("The world is Flat", date,pub.getPublisherID(), "037889948837", "099887636627", "Thomas L. Friedman");
```

And it is giving me an error

My Publisher class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Publisher {
    static int  publisherCounter;
    protected static int publisherID;
    protected static String publisherName;
    private String publisherAddress;
    private String contactName;
    private ArrayList publications;

    public Publisher(String publisherName, String publisherAddress,
            String contactName) {
        super();
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
        this.publisherAddress = publisherAddress;
        this.contactName = contactName;
        publisherCounter++;
        publisherID = publisherCounter;
    }
    public static String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }
    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }
    public String getPublisherAddress() {
        return publisherAddress;
    }
    public void setPublisherAddress(String publisherAddress) {
        this.publisherAddress = publisherAddress;
    }
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String printPublisherDetails(){
        return publisherID+publisherName+publisherAddress+contactName;
    }
    public String printAllPublications(){
        return Publication.getPulicationTitle() + Journal.getArticleTitle();
    }
    public static int getPublisherID() {
        return publisherID;
    }
    public ArrayList getPublications() {
        return publications;
    }
    public void addPublication(String adds){
        publications.add(adds);
    }



}
```

Comment: Book constructor expects a Publisher object, no the publisherID (a number?)

Comment: *And it is giving me an error* -- what error are you getting? Be specific.

Comment: I know that the problem is that it has to be of type Publisher . and I know that if I change it into the constructor into a string it will work but it has to be of type Publisher. Maybe I should create another constructor in my Publisher class that only accepts the Id. I don't know really!

Comment: ClassCastException most likely. The constructor expects a Publisher object, not whatever is returned by the `getPublisherId()` method. My question is: what expects the publisher ID to be provided?

Comment: @DavidHammen Eclipss's suggestion says that I have to change they type of the Publisher into a String

Comment: post your publisher class code

Comment: @DanTemple the publisher ID is of type String in my Publisher class

Comment: @Naveen Okay I will post it

Comment: you're missing a couple `this`es in the constructor. `ISBN_10 = ISBN_10;` does nothing

Comment: @peeskillet You are right

Answer (score 0):

Your Book constructor accepts an Publisher object and you are passing the publisher ID, either change your Book constructor or overload it :-

```
public Book(String pulicationTitle, Date publicationDate,  int publisherId,  String ISBN_10, String ISBN_13, String authorName) {
    super(pulicationTitle, publicationDate, publisherId);
    ISBN_10 = ISBN_10;
    ISBN_13 = ISBN_13;
    this.authorName = authorName;
    bookCounter++;
}
```

Also change or overload publisher constructor since it accepts different parameters:-

```
public Publisher(String publicationTitle,Date publicationDate,int publicationId){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems in the code.The below modifications can solve some part of your code

Book class constructor is expecting `Publisher object` in your code but you are passing `primitive type`

Add the code below

You can have overloaded constructor

```
public Book(String pulicationTitle, Date publicationDate, String ISBN_10, String ISBN_13, String authorName) {
//operations
}
```

You can have a method in Book class like this pass the id expicitly using method call

```
public void getpubId(int pubId)
{
// use pubId
}
```

call the method from your testing class like this

```
    //create book object
Book book = new Book("The world is Flat", date, "037889948837", "099887636627", "Thomas L. Friedman"); 
//instead of passing publisher id through constructor, pass it through a method call 
        book.getpubId(publisher.getId());
```

Comment: the problem is that my Assignment has to be of Type Publisher